# can I use a cat5 connected router to repeat a wireless signal?

Tags: wireless

This is a home networking question. I have a linksys G router that I would like to use as wireless repeater and wired hub.  I can connect it to my wired cat5 connection in my house. The primary wireless signal is weak in the area but I figured that because it was connected to the wired signal it could become an access point that repeats the wired signal. 
How can I set this router up to best eliminate the wireless dead zone in the room? (I figured repeating the weak primary signal would not help but the wired connection is fast.)

Comment: This question is not on topic here. You can consider asking this at [su].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes! using Ethernet is much better.

Repeater can work fast as Ethernet too only if the repeater have something called "full bridging", & good signal to repeat, anyway cat5! speed around 10Mbps and 100Mbps, if you need something higher than that use CAT5e

If you want your wireless cover big areas make sure you have choose the right channel and band, try to put it in higher place and in the middle of the room or house.

- B transfer rate 11mbps 150 feet 2.4GHz
- G transfer rate 54mbps 150    feet 2.4GHz

Comment: Category-5 hasn't been a recognized cable rating for 15 years (since before the turn of the century). The Category-5 recognition was pulled just like Catgegory-1, Category-2, and Category-4; those categories no longer exist. Category-5E completely replaced it in 1999.

Comment: We still use CAT5e here in turkey, I have never touched cat6 but I saw fiber optic once, which is nice :(

Comment: Category-5E is a recognized cable, but Category-5 is not. In reality, 5E replaced 5.